# Concrete Mathematics book I don't understand conversion in (1.1) to (1.3)

Tags: inequality

I started reading the book Concrete Mathematics 2nd edition and there is a conversion I don't understand(*is in page 4 of the book, equation(1.3)*), it says:

We have 2 equations:

$T_0 + 1 = 1$

$T_{n+1} = 2T_{n-1} + 2$

Now, if we let     $U_n = T_n + 1$, we have

$U_0 = 1$;       `//I understand this substitution`

$U_n = 2U_{n-1}$ `//this is the substitution(on the right side) it has no sense to me`

It should be(according to me):

Since $2T_{n-1} + 2$ can be expressed as $2T_{n-1} + 1 + 1$

the conversion should be:

$2U_{n-1}+1$

thanks for your help guys

Comment: $2T_{n-1}+2=2(T_{n-1}+1)=2U_{n-1}.$

Comment: Is it $U_n = 2U_{n-1}$ or $U_{n+1} = 2U_{n-1}$?

Comment: When it says, let $U_n = T_n + 1$, what they really mean is that $U_k = T_k + 1$ for any $k$, so you not only have $U_n = T_n + 1$, but also $U_{n-1} = T_{n-1} + 1$

Comment: Your second equation does not match the text. In _Concrete Mathematics_, the equation written is $T_n+1=2T_{n-1}+2$.

Comment: Please, don't add links to online version of copyrighted material,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the book, the  recurrence  presented was,

$$T_{n}=2T_{n-1}+1$$

What is actually written down is,

$$T_{n}+1=2T_{n-1}+2$$

Which nicely shows that,

$$T_{n}+1=2(T_{n-1}+1)$$

---

A general trick is to look for a particular solution to the recurrence and then look at the solution to the homogenous equation.

There exists a constant solution to the recurrence,

$$T_{n}=2T_{n-1}+1$$

$$-1=2(-1)+1$$

Subtracting the second equation (which shows the constant solution is $-1$) from the first gives,

$$T_{n}+1=2(T_{n-1}+1)$$

With $U_{n}=T_{n}+1$ we have,

$$U_{n+1}=2U_{n}$$

Which is nothing but the corresponding homogenous recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading wrongly what the book says: the recurrence before (1.3) is
\begin{align}
&T_0+1=1 \\
&T_n+1=2T_{n-1}+2
\end{align}
which stems from the recurrence (1.1), namely
\begin{align}
&T_0=0 \\
&T_n=2T_{n-1}+1
\end{align}
You are reading the second line in the first display as
$$
\color{red}{T_{n+1}=2T_{n-1}+2}\quad\leftarrow\text{wrong!}
$$
which is quite different and not what is in the book.

If $U_n=T_n+1$, then we obviously get
\begin{align}
&U_0=1 \\
&U_n=2U_{n-1}
\end{align}